# Append channels of zero to tensor in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I want to append channels with al zero as values to an existing tensor with the limitation of a flexible batch size. So I can not use `tf.concat` and concatenate my tensor with `tf.zeros`. I thought about something like `tf.pad`, but I need to do it in the last/fourth dimension.

**EDIT:**

Here is an example:

I have an array of [8, 300, 300, 3] with specific values:
e.g.

`tensor_1 = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.random([8,300, 300, 3]))`

Now I want to expand the number of the last dimensions to e.g. 6 with  a complete zero tensor.

If I have a static batch size I just can do the following:

`zeros = tf.zeros(tensor_1.shape) 
result = tf.concat([tensor_1, zeros])`

But if the first dimension is `None` `tf.zeros` returns an error. So I need method that does not depend on knowing the batch size.

Comment: What does "append channels with all zeroes as values to an existing tensor" mean exactly? Could you provide an example?

Comment: I posted some code to explain more in detail.